# transforming begin date and end date into a table with just begin date.

Tags: r

I would like to turn the following table into a two column matrix incrementing by an hour.

Data:

```
START<-as.POSIXct(c("2017-07-13 01:40:00 MDT", "2017-07-21 06:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-21 14:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-24 11:00:00 MDT",
    "2017-07-24 12:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-25 05:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-25 17:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-26 12:00:00 MDT",
    "2017-07-30 12:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-31 04:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-31 15:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-03 18:30:00 MDT",
    "2017-08-03 23:30:00 MDT", "2017-08-09 05:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-09 20:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-14 09:00:00 MDT",
    "2017-08-16 05:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-16 07:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-16 19:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-17 18:00:00 MDT",
    "2017-08-20 05:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-23 06:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-23 14:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-24 17:00:00 MDT",
    "2017-08-28 00:00:00 MDT"))

END<-as.POSIXct(c("2017-07-21 06:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-21 14:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-24 11:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-24 12:00:00 MDT",
"2017-07-25 05:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-25 17:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-26 12:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-30 12:00:00 MDT",
"2017-07-31 04:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-31 15:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-03 18:30:00 MDT", "2017-08-03 23:30:00 MDT",
"2017-08-09 05:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-09 20:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-14 09:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-16 05:00:00 MDT",
"2017-08-16 07:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-16 19:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-17 18:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-20 05:00:00 MDT",
"2017-08-23 06:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-23 14:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-24 17:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-28 00:00:00 MDT",
"2017-09-28 13:00:00 MDT"))

RATE<-c(1485, 0, 1485,  880, 1485, 0, 1485, 1100, 1485, 0, 1485, 1483, 1485, 0, 1485, 1419, 880, 0, 1419, 1485, 1419, 0, 1100, 419, 1100)

DF<-data.frame(START, END, RATE)
```

The result would be something like:

Date<-c("2017-07-13 01:00:00 MDT",  "2017-07-13 02:00:00 MDT",  "2017-07-13 03:00:00 MDT",......, "2017-09-28 13:00:00 MDT")

values<-c(1485, 1485, 1485,....., 1100)

Is there a function would do this?

I was thinking about getting a list of dates by:

```
tStartDateTime<-trunc(DF$START[1], units = "hours")

tEndDateTime<-trunc(max(DF$END), units = "hours")+60*60

tHours<-difftime( DF,tStartDateTime, units = "hours")

TableHours<-seq(from=tStartDateTime, by="1 hours", length.out=tHours )
```

But I'm unsure how to fill in the resulting table with the values between.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most elegant solution, but you could expand each row of your data into separate data.frame using `lapply`. Each of these data.frame consist of two columns - time: hourly from start to end time, rate: replicate RATE for corresponding row. `do.call(rbind, ...)` convert the list of data.frame to a single data.frame.

```
library(lubridate)

tmp <- lapply(seq(nrow(DF)), function(x) data.frame(
               time = seq(floor_date(DF$START[x], "hour"),
                          ceiling_date(DF$END[x], "hour"), 
                          "hour"),
               rate = DF$RATE[x]))

do.call(rbind, tmp)
```

Comment: That's a pretty neat solution to a multi( i.e. > 2) dimensional problem, You created a "long" form of a sparse array that has the starting time axis on one side and the ending times on another. and the `RATES`'s are the values?

Comment: @42- Yup. The rate is the value.

Comment: I am a little unsure if `lubridate::ceiling_date` is appropriate for the end-timing in the solution, since it did result in a couple of duplicated time.  Probably would be more consistent to just use `floor_date` throughout.